# Find all elements except those of a given attribute using jQuery

Tags: jquery

How would I do the following, but exclude any hidden inputs?

```
$("#new-ticket").find('input,select,textarea').val('');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `:visible`

```
$("#new-ticket").find('input,select,textarea').filter(':visible').val('');
```

or

```
$("#new-ticket").find(':input:visible').val('');
```

the `:input` selector selects all input, textarea, select and button elements.

Comment: Thanks. Never new about `:input`.  If I wanted to include hidden selects and textareas, would it just be something like `$("#new-ticket").find('input:visible,select,textarea').filter(':visible').val('');`

Comment: No, you'd either use the filter to filter the entire collection, as in the first example in the answer, or you'd have to use it on each of the targeted elements, as in -> `$("#new-ticket").find('input:visible ,select:visible ,textarea:visible ')`